# Does Play 2 has a built-in migration tool?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get some information about Play 2 Database migrations I need it in my thesis, but during my research I saw that Play 2 documentation is not organized as Django and Rails.
So could you help by telling me if it has migration tool or plug-in?
if plug-in which one is more popular with Play 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. You can check the docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Evolutions)